# I can't load configuration scss file in vuejs using sass-resources-loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass-loader

**webpack.base.conf.js**

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
        sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
    options: {
      resources: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/scss/_variables.scss')
    }
  },
```

My "variables" file starts to load, but then i get this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| $white: #ffffff;
| 
| // The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
```

I use this manual:

https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

vue version: 2.93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually i created project from scratch using vue-cli@3
and added to **vue.config.js** this code:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const oneOfsMap = config.module.rule('scss').oneOfs.store
    oneOfsMap.forEach(item => {
      item
        .use('sass-resources-loader')
        .loader('sass-resources-loader')
        .options({
          resources: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss/_variables.scss'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss/_mixins.scss'),
          ]
        })
        .end()
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add it to a *vue.config.js* file in your root directory. If the file doesn't exist, create it and add something along the lines of this (my config):

```
module.exports = {
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/assets/_variables.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working for me. Should i make some changes in my webpack.base.conf.js ?

Comment: Have you installed with vue cli? If you're using the config above, you won't need your code in webpack config. Make sure you have the following under devDependencies in package.json as well:

  "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",

Comment: Yes. I have these dependencies. It looks like webpack ignores my vue.config.js .

Comment: You should now use "prependData" instead of "data" which is deprecated now (sass-loader v8)